# RSpec any_instance stubbing on object initialised in function

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec, stub

Disclaimer: I'm very new to RSpec and TDD in general, so I may be going about this the wrong way entirely.

I want to write a command-line interface to my program which takes a command and generates a class to handle it.  The way the program is intended to work is similar to tools like git and svn; i.e. you could pass "srs init" to initialise the program, "srs add" to add something to it, and so forth.

So I have a class which takes ARGV and passes it off to a specific handler, which looks like this:

```
class CLI
    def run!(*arguments)
        command = arguments.shift
        case command
        when "init"
            CLI::Init.new.run!(*arguments)
        end
    end
end
```

My Init handler would then look like this:

```
class CLI
    class Init
        def initialize()
        end
        def run!(*arguments)
        end
    end
end
```

I am trying to write a test suite for the CLI class's routing functionality.  RSpec fails if I use the following:

```
describe CLI do
    it "should launch the Init handler if we pass init" do
        CLI::Init.any_instance.should_receive(:run!)
        CLI::run!(*["init"])
    end
end
```

However it passes if I replace the call to `CLI::run!` with a direct call to the Init handler's run; i.e.:-

```
describe CLI do
    it "should launch the Init handler if we pass init" do
        CLI::Init.any_instance.should_receive(:run!)
        CLI::Init.new.run!(*[])
    end
end
```

It looks as if any_instance only works on instances defined/constructed within the `describe` block, but I'm not really sure.  If anyone can offer me any guidance either on how I can check that a class method has been called on an instance constructed inside my `run!` function, or on a better way to test this functionality in the first place, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: How does it fail? Can you show the trace? Your code looks ok at first glance.

Comment: @x1a4, took another look after reading your comment, and you're right!  I had simplified the code for this post, and the simplified code works OK.. should have tested it failed in the same way before posting.  Will post up an answer explaining what the problem was once my eight-hour limit has expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes explaining the problem reveals the answer.  In actual fact, the name of the handler, "Init" was being passed as a parameter to the `describe` block, more like this:

```
%w{Init}.each do |cmd|
    describe CLI do
        it "should launch the #{cmd} handler if we pass #{cmd}" do
            CLI.const_get(cmd).any_instance.should_receive(:run!)
           CLI::run!(*[cmd])
        end
    end
end
```

In describing the problem I took out the loop to simplify the question, but in doing so made a crucial change -- the name of the class, Init, began with a capital "I", while the name of the command passed to the command line, init, begins with a small "i".

So it turned out the test failed correctly, because I tried to pass the command "Init" when I should have been passing the command "init".

TL;DR -- the original code *does* actually work!  Sorry for the bother.